# What is the highest amount of EXP I can get from any heists?

Tags: payday-2

Right now I have hit III-0 and would like to level up quickly. I hate doing small heists because they are tedious and don't net the best exp/time.

So what heist can net me the most exp? Including boosts, because I'm not sure how those work and how I can set myself up to get more exp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking recent DLC into account, I would argue that "The Golden Grin Casino" is one of the better heists to level up quickly. It can reliably be done solo in stealth on deathwish difficulty in about 20 minutes once you get the hang of it, and it gives quite a bit of exp (I usually take a few minutes to haul all the money as well, by opening the game to public once everything is clear).

Answer (score 1):

Hoxton Breakout: This mission looks like it gives the most experience. It's possible the train job might do more, but i don't know the stats on it, and it's a rare chance you ever get to the job as it is.

[image]

Comment: oof that payout though.

Comment: @thebluefish I know right...

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that Hoxton Breakout Overkill is much easier than Death Wish. Even coordinated groups may find their xp/time much higher from Overkill because of the number of attempts a Death Wish run may take (if the group is capable of it at all).

Comment: Also, each successful Death Wish run would take considerably longer than a successful Overkill run (you can't move to mission objectives as easily).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to net the most exp is to do the following:

1. Run a Framing Frame on Deathwish as a Pro Job and fully stealth it

   - This nets you a Stealth Bonus of +25% on your next heist
   - This also nets you an additional +15% exp boost if you have a perk deck fully completed
2. Run a Hoxton Breakout Deathwish as a Pro Job. With the exp you get. This gets you to an exp level of around ~1.4 million, and adding a 40% boost will net you nearly ~2 million points of exp.

Found this information through going through user [/u/Viruzzz's](http://reddit.com/u/viruzzz) [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P3lbloyNltIWQHuL8-ZZLJUCNbAcQdrxTnHQhqpczuY/edit#gid=1954495000) on exp levels. This is done under the assumption you are at Infamy V, have gotten your perk decks to rank 4, and have a full party.  This gets you nearly ~3,000,000 exp.

Answer (score 0):

this is a question with varied answers, all of the above are good but it depends on what you are willing to do.

Hoxton Breakout is the highest RAW payout, meaning you only have to beat the heist to get the reward, but you dont get any additional loot (bar some ATMs on day 1)

Cook off or white XMAS both work as infinite loot sources but, simply put, its challenging and the initial payout is low, you need t stay a while to get much out of it.

Golden Grin and Framing Frame are very good for the payouts in a short(ish) time, if you are sneaky.

Ideally, GGC for stealth and Hoxout for loud. Hoxout DW pro will take about 40-60 minutes and pays out about 12 or 14 million into your offshore account

Answer (score -1):

Rats, period.
It is the highest raw experience you can get and also pays itself off so buying it isn't an issue.

Comment: Please don't use all-caps.

Answer (score -2):

Jewelery Store (No risk) I find it to be the highest paying mission out of all of the PayDay2 heists...

[image]

Answer (score -3):

uh.. Its pretty obviously Cook Off Death Wish. I did it today, on Overkill, got 32 bags (no cheats spent 2 hours) and got 16 million xp.

Comment: You may want to expand a bit on your answer, don't use such abbreviations